# Proof verification: Prove V is infinite-dimensional iff there exists an infinite sequence

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I am kindly asking for someone to give me some feedback on my proof:

The proposition is:
"Prove that V is infinite-dimensional iff there exists a sequence $v_1,v_2,...$ of vectors in V such that $v_1,v_2,...,v_m$ is linearly independent for every positive integer $m$".

I already did and checked $(\Rightarrow)$.

The other way is the one i am asking for feedback. My proof is by contradiction:

Suppose V is finite-dimensional. Then there is a list of vectors $v_1,v_2,...,v_k$, for some positive integer k such that $Span(v_1,v_2,...,v_k)=V$. Therefore there exist $a_1,...,a_k$ in F such that $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_3v_m = v_{k+1}$, for some vector $v_{k+1}$ in V. But then $v_1,v_2,...,v_k,v_{k+1}$ will not be linearly independent. We arrived to a contradiction. Therefore V is infinite-dimensional.

I am aware of similar questions such as:
[An exercise about the proof of an infinite-dimensional vector space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1267373/an-exercise-about-the-proof-of-an-infinite-dimensional-vector-space) , [Show that a infinite dimensional vector space must have linearly independent vectors for every positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885420/show-that-a-infinite-dimensional-vector-space-must-have-linearly-independent-vec)

etc.

But if found none including my prove.

Thank you.

Comment: Proof seems fine. You can be a bit more clear, just saying in an n-dimensional vector space any n+1 vectors must be linearly dependent.